# Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Subscription'

Tags: json, angular

Estou querendo mapear as lista de perguntas e jogá-las na propriedade perguntas do meu objeto JSON, mas ai no prompt dá esse erro:

> "ERROR in src/app/form/perguntas/perguntas.component.ts(19,5): error
>   TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Pergunta[]'.
>   Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Subscription'."

**Esse é meu perguntas component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Pergunta } from '../perguntas/pergunta.model'
import { PerguntasService } from '../perguntas.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-perguntas',
  templateUrl: './perguntas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./perguntas.component.css']
})
export class PerguntasComponent implements OnInit {

  perguntas: Pergunta[]

  constructor(private perguntasService: PerguntasService) { }
 //ass
  ngOnInit() {
    this.perguntas = this.perguntasService.perguntas()
        .subscribe(perguntas => this.perguntas = perguntas)
  }

}
```

**Aqui é o meu serviço:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Pergunta } from './perguntas/pergunta.model'
import { PerguntasComponent } from './perguntas/perguntas.component'
import { Http} from '@angular/http'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { MEAT_API} from '../app.api'

@Injectable()
export class PerguntasService{

  constructor(private http:Http){}




    perguntas(): Observable<Pergunta[]>{
      return this.http.get(`${MEAT_API}/perguntas`)
      .map( response => response.json())
    }



}
```

**e meu app modules:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ROUTES } from './app.routes';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FormComponent } from './form/form.component';
import { PerguntasComponent } from './form/perguntas/perguntas.component';
import { OpcoesComponent } from './form/perguntas/opcoes/opcoes.component';
import { PerguntasService } from './form/perguntas.service';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FormComponent,
    PerguntasComponent,
    OpcoesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
     HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),
    ModalModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [PerguntasService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: acredito que você tenha esquecido de fornecer o erro que ocorreu

Comment: ERROR in src/app/form/perguntas/perguntas.component.ts(19,5): error TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Pergunta[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Subscription'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema é que você está tentando atribuir o resultado do *subscribe* à sua lista de `Pergunta`, quando o valor já é aplicado dentro do primeiro *callback*.

Portanto, faça a seguinte modificação:

**perguntas.component.ts**

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.perguntaService
        .perguntas()
        .subscribe(perguntas => this.perguntas = perguntas);
}
```

Comment: cara, assim dá mais erro :(

Comment: pode me dizer quais erros? pois eu implementei localmente aqui e funcionou como o esperado.

Comment: ERROR in app/form/perguntas/perguntas.component.ts(19,5): error TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Pergunta[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Subscription'.
app/form/perguntas/perguntas.component.ts(20,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Observable'.

Comment: você falou em colocar o perguntas: Observable<Pergunta[]>, dentro do meu subscribe?

Comment: @ttlelis_12 eu tinha entendido errado o problema. Atualizei a resposta, por gentileza verifique se o que proponho resolve.

Comment: sabe aquele momento que seu problema tá tão bosta,que tá foda, e você tipo não sabe o porque tá dando esse erro mais ahahah

Comment: @ttlelis_12 ainda o mesmo erro? Se copiar e colar a minha modificação no método `ngOnInit` no seu componente `perguntas.component.ts` é para funcionar. É só essa a mudança.

Comment: funcionou huhuh thanks

Comment: @ttlelis_12 considere marcar a resposta como aceita caso tenha resolvido todos a questão.